# How to square all the values in a vector in R?

Tags: r, perfect-square

I would like to square every value in `data`, and I am thinking about using a for loop like this:

```
data = rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=1)
Newdata = {L = NULL;  for (i in data)  {i = i*i}  L = i  return (L)}
```

Answer (score 62):

Try this (faster and simpler):

```
newData <- data^2
```

Comment: @user3230065 I recommend you take a look to [the Quick R tutorial](http://statmethods.net).

Answer (score 18):

This will also work

```
newData <- data*data
```

Comment: It's also twice as fast as `data^2`!

Answer (score 9):

How about `sapply` (not really necessary for this simple case):

```
newData<- sapply(data, function(x) x^2)
```

Comment: I don't know how this is even different/better from the answer provided by @Barranka

Comment: its will be even slower than the vectorized implementation. sapply is an compact way of writing a loop!

Answer (score 0):

This is another simple way:

`sq_data <- data**2`